# Angular Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a simple news ticker which seems to work fine on my codepen example. It seems i having a problem with integration - code structure. As it stands I am receiving the following error.

```
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Here is my a code snippet of my controller.

```
"use strict";

 var app = angular.module('portlandApp');

// WEB SERVICE GET REQUEST
var NewsService = function ($http){
this.$http = $http;
}

NewsService.prototype.getarticles = function () {
return this.$http.get('app/data/news.json').then(function (response){
    return response.data;
});
  };

app.service("newsService", NewsService);

angular
 .module('portlandApp')
 .controller('newsCtrl', ['$scope', 'newsService', '$location', '$interval',   '$timeout', function($scope, newsService, $location, $timeout, $interval) {

 var promise = newsService.getarticles();
  promise.then(function (data){
  $scope.articles = data.news.map(function(item) {
    //item.date = moment().format('Do MMMM YYYY');
    return item;
  });
console.log(data)
 });
 // AMOUNT OF ARTICLES
   $scope.articleLimit = 4;

// NEWS TICKER FUNCTION
$scope.moving = false;

$scope.moveLeft = function() {
    $scope.moving = true;
    $timeout($scope.switchFirst, 1000);
};
$scope.switchFirst = function () {
    $scope.news.push($scope.newsLink.shift());
    $scope.moving = false;
    $scope.$apply();
};

$interval($scope.moveLeft, 2000);


 }]);
```

Comment: Initialise '$scope.news = []' first... before you access it.. I dont see anywhere such declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
// NEWS TICKER FUNCTION
$scope.moving = false;


$scope.news = []  // need to define array before push value.

enter code here

$scope.moveLeft = function() {
   $scope.moving = true;
   $timeout($scope.switchFirst, 1000);
 };
$scope.switchFirst = function () {
   $scope.news.push($scope.newsLink.shift());
   $scope.moving = false;
   $scope.$apply();
 };
```

Comment: I don't this that's the case . I have made a edit to my code snippet. I have already defined my array before pushing my value, using a web service

Comment: you have to define array in JavaScript also

Answer (score 2):

You never intialize $scope.news, just add `$scope.news = []` at the beginning of the controller

Comment: I don't this that's the case . I have made a edit to my code snippet

Comment: In your updated snippet, there still not initialization of $scope.news

Answer (score 0):

At the very beggining of your controller, declare that `$scope.news= []`

When you add values to your $scope.news, this variable is undefined